# Intersection of Collection of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to figure out the value of
$$ \bigcap_{ r \in \mathbb{R}, r > 1 } (-r, r) $$

My guess is that its $(-1, 1)$.

Comment: Consideration: Is $[-1,1]$ contained in the intersection?

Comment: What Mnifldz said, if you see that, than ask yourself, is there a larger subset that is contained?

Comment: I don't think you mean $A \in S$ -- after all, $S$ is an interval, $A$ is a subset, i.e. $A \subseteq S$ but not $A \in S$...

Comment: gt6989b, $S$ looks like a collection of sets which are themselves intervals, but it's not an interval itself.

Comment: yes I do see where [-1,1] is contained in the intersection.

Answer (score 2):

Show three things:

(1) For all $x$ in $[-1, 1]$, $x \in (-r, r)$ for any $r > 1$. This will prove that $[-1, 1]$ is in the intersection.

(2) For all $x > 1$, there exists an $r$ such that $x \notin (-r, r)$. Hint take $r = (x - 1) / 2$. This will show that anything greater than 1 isn't in the intersection.

(3) For all $x < -1$, there exists an $r$ such that $x \notin (-r, r)$. Similar to (2).

These three things show that the intersection equals $[-1,1]$.